# Move every Fourth Lines data to four lines above

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file that could be exponentially long. I need to take every 4th line and move it four lines above.

```
  0   1 BXP_0_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-1    3.2 (35.0)  3.4 (35.4)  1.25 (19.2) 1.11 (25.9)  site_A (15,11)
  0   1 BXP_1_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-2    4.3 (36.3)  3.2 (35.0)  1.26 (18.8) 1.20 (21.0)  site_B (16,10)
  0   1 BXP_2_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-3    4.4 (36.4)  3.1 (34.9)  1.34 (16.7) 1.11 (25.3)  site_C (15,11)
AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-1,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=A
AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-2,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=B
AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-3,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=C
```

What i want it to look like is:

```
  0   1 BXP_0_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-1    3.2 (35.0)  3.4 (35.4)  1.25 (19.2) 1.11 (25.9)  site_A (15,11) AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-1,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=A
  0   1 BXP_1_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-2    4.3 (36.3)  3.2 (35.0)  1.26 (18.8) 1.20 (21.0)  site_B (16,10) AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-2,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=B
  0   1 BXP_2_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-3    4.4 (36.4)  3.1 (34.9)  1.34 (16.7) 1.11 (25.3)  site_C (15,11) AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-3,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=C
```

It cuts it off but the output should all be on online so it would take those six lines and give me just 3 lines. I would need this to do it for as many lines that are as in the file.

Comment: If the file is longer, do you still want to move every fourth line, or does each half of the file grow?

Answer (score 1):

try this line, I just read your data used `\s and \S`, you can change the `regex` in grep, to fit your needs

```
paste <(grep '^\s' file) <(grep '^\S' file)
```

it outputs:

```
kent$  paste <(grep '^\s' f) <(grep '^\S' f)                                                                                                                                
  0   1 BXP_0_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-1    3.2 (35.0)  3.4 (35.4)  1.25 (19.2) 1.11 (25.9)  site_A (15,11)    AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-1,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=A
  0   1 BXP_1_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-2    4.3 (36.3)  3.2 (35.0)  1.26 (18.8) 1.20 (21.0)  site_B (16,10)    AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-2,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=B
  0   1 BXP_2_1  RRUS11B12  RRU-3    4.4 (36.4)  3.1 (34.9)  1.34 (16.7) 1.11 (25.3)  site_C (15,11)    AuxPlugInUnit=RRU-3,RiPort=DATA_1 Subrack=1,Slot=1,PlugInUnit=1,RiPort=C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne'
  chomp;
  push @r, $_;
  if ($. %3 ==0) { print "$_ ", scalar <> for @r; @r=() }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as kev, I assumed you want to merge the two halves of the file.

Count the number of lines in the file. Then, keep two open file handles to the same file, one of them pointing at the beginning, the second one to the middle line. Then just read one line from each file handle and print:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = shift;
open my $IN, '<', $filename or die $!;

1 while (<$IN>);
my $line_count = $.;
die "Odd number of lines.\n" if $line_count % 2;
seek $IN, 0, 0;

open my $SECOND, '<', $filename or die $!;
<$SECOND> for 1 .. $line_count / 2;
for (1 .. $line_count / 2) {
    chomp(my $first = <$IN>);
    print $first, scalar <$SECOND>;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl data > data.new`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&³/
1 {h;b
  }
2,3 {H;b
  }

x;H;g
s/²\([^³]*\)³\(\n\)²\([^³]*\)³\(.*\)/\3 \1\4/
P
s/^[^²]*²/²/
h
' YourFile
```

Need of 2 delimiter (arbitrary `²` and `³`). Just ensure that they are not used char. If this is the case and no other delimiter could be found, a first pre action is to escape delimiter in text and put back as post treatment

Answer (score 0):

```
n=$(( $(wc -l < file) / 2 ))
awk -v n=$n 'NR<=n {line[NR]=$0; next} {printf "%s %s\n", line[NR-n], $0}' file
```